# maintaining ordering when using unique fuction in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, indexing

I have some code, where the following, say, are the columns of my df.

```
df.columns = ['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2', 'D1', 'D2', 'E1', 'E2']

list = df.columns.str[:1]
list = np.unique(list)
```

I am trying to get the unique values of the letters, and numbers, but in the correct order.

My code doesn't maintain the ordering and I cant figure out how to do so.

Thank you

expected output:

```
letters = [A, B, C, D, E]
numbers = [1, 2]
```

Comment: is it always one letter and one number? or it can change?

Comment: What is `df`? Pandas DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`toolz.unique`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) instead. This is identical to the `unique_everseen` [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) found in the `itertools` docs. Internally, it iterates while maintaining a `set` of seen items.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2', 'D1', 'D2', 'E1', 'E2'])

from toolz import unique

res = list(unique(df.columns.str[:1]))

['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

A more Pandorable solution would be to convert the `Index` object to `pd.Series` and use `drop_duplicates`. This, again, uses hashing:

```
res = df.columns.str[:1].to_series().drop_duplicates().values

array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your example is representative, you can use a neat little trick that I got from [Raymond Hettinger](https://twitter.com/raymondh?lang=en). In python 3.6 and later, dicts are ordered so you can use their keys as efficient ordered sets.

```
list(dict.fromkeys(c[0] for c in df.columns))
# --> ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

list(dict.fromkeys(int(c[1]) for c in df.columns))
# --> [1, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks FHTMitchell; I need to update my python in that case as im on a 2. version.

Answer (score 1):

This one uses regex and would continue working in case you have multiple characters/numbers in your column names:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['EE2', 'A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2', 'D1', 'D11', 'E1'])

split_ = [re.findall('\d+|\D+', col) for col in df.columns]

list(pd.Series([col[0] for col in split_]).drop_duplicates())
# ['EE', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
list(pd.Series([col[1] for col in split_]).drop_duplicates())
# ['2', '1', '11']
```

Comment: Im am further looking into this as indeed I have EUR3m EUR3m3m GBP6m3m as my columns, so this is indeed more helpful.

however, taking EUR3m3m as an example, regex spits the EUR just fine, but then splits 3m3m into 3 , m , 3 , m (as opposed to desired output of "3m3m"

could u explain "re.findall('\d+|\D+'" to me such that I can amend the code to take EUR and GBP in list 1, 
and 3m, 3m3m, 6m3m in the second list?